# Sort by Character column 'priority' in sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table with a coulmn name priority with values :

```
Urgent, medium, low, high.
```

I want to apply order by such that after order by values are ordered like this:

```
urgent
high 
medium
low
```

How can I do This

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression for that:

```
ORDER BY CASE Priority 
    WHEN 'urgent' THEN 1
    WHEN 'high' THEN 2
    WHEN 'medium' THEN 3
    WHEN 'low' THEN 4
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from your_table
order by case when priority = 'urgent' then 1
              when priority = 'high' then 2
              when priority = 'medium' then 3
              when priority = 'low' then 4
         end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do an `ORDER BY` `CASE WHEN` type of query, where you assign a numerical value to each text, although I recommend using an integer to indicate priotity level in your data directly.